# Issue with Authorize.Net payment gateway logo

Tags: laravel, authorize.net, seal

If we don't include the code given below then is there any chances that payments get failed in live site?

```
<!-- (c) 2005, 2019. Authorize.Net is a registered trademark of CyberSource Corporation -->
<div class="AuthorizeNetSeal">
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var ANS_customer_id = "my-customer-id";</script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//verify.authorize.net:443/anetseal/seal.js"></script>
</div>
```

I am using the Laravel framework.

Comment: `Accept.js` is a JavaScript library for sending secure payment data directly to `Authorize.Net`. `Accept.js` captures the payment data and submits it directly to them, in exchange for a one-time-use token, or payment nonce. You can use this payment nonce in the place of payment data in a follow-on createTransactionRequest API call.

Comment: And read this article about the seal logo https://account.authorize.net/help/Account/Verified_Merchant_Seal/Secure_Payments_Seal.htm

Comment: I updated my question. please have a look. thank you

Comment: yes, I read that. so it's not necessary. right? As after removing that some payments got failed. So that's why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This seal has absolutely no effect on the processing of transactions through Authorize.Net. That seal exist solely so you can show your users that you a valid and active Authorize.Net merchant. Nothing more, nothing less.